# How fix datatables and page footer

Tags: html, css, datatables, footer

I have problem with js-fix-footer and datatable, when i using datatables ajax data, datatables is under footer, and page looks like above:

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8JUr.png)

And footer is always on top, when normaly is not, and footer is only on page bottom.

Im using this fix-footer: https://github.com/FrontendMatter/fix-footer/tree/master

And page template is from frontendmetter: tutorio template bootstrap.

Im tried used another css but isnt working

Comment: You should add your code here and adding more contexts to your question if you want help.  Where is your CSS? Your JS? Like this, the community can't help you.